# How to fire a notification on a particular date of every month?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

How to get the 5th date of every month. So far I know how to get the current date. I just want to fire out local notification for 5th of every month.

Here is my code:

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
 if (!localNotification){
         return; 
 }
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];   
 NSDate *dateToFire = ?;  // please give me logic to find out 5th of evry month


 [localNotification setFireDate:dateToFire];
 [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];


 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value 1", @"Value 2", nil];
 NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"payload"];
 [localNotification setUserInfo:data];



 [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Incoming Local Notification" ];
 [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
 [localNotification setHasAction:YES];      

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: How long do you want to set the notification? 5th of Every month for next one year?

Comment: Sudha: you can use a timer and use date part to extract date. Compare it to 5. If it result to YES...post a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, then you may do this way:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
if(day==5){
     //your logic starts or make some flag here.
}
```